# Error: 'Method must have a return type'

Tags: c#, methods, return-type

The problem i'm getting is that at berekenBTW I keep getting the "method must have a return type" error and I really don't know how to solve this. I've been searching here at sof but i'm new to C# and the other questions are just to hard for me to understand.

What i'm trying to do is the following:

1. I'm telling the user to enter a price.
2. readLine
3. convert the price to a double since i'm going to calculte the taxes later on
4. I want to use method berekenBTW with the double in which I calculate the taxes and the return the taxes
5. and then the rest of the code after berekenBTW(nieuwe_prijs) only thing is that the variable btw must be filled with the return of berekenBTW(nieuwe_prijs)

   `static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           // methode vraagGebrokenGetal & methode berekenBTW
           Console.WriteLine("geef een prijs op:");
           string prijs = Console.ReadLine();
           double nieuwe_prijs = Convert.ToDouble(prijs);
           berekenBTW(nieuwe_prijs);
           Console.WriteLine("De prijs was:");
           Console.WriteLine(nieuwe_prijs);
           Console.WriteLine("De btw is:");
           Console.WriteLine(btw);
           Console.WriteLine("De prijs plus de btw is:");
           Console.WriteLine(nieuwe_prijs + btw);
           Console.ReadLine();
       }`

   ```
   private static berekenBTW(double prijs)
   {
       double btw = prijs * 0.21;
       return btw;
   }
   ```

I really hope someone can help me out and if I need to clarify just ask. I'm allways eager to learn

Comment: You're missing a return type on `berekenBTW`.  (Closing as typographical error)

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: `private static double berekenBTW(double prijs) { ... }`

Comment: The error is self explanatory. And looking at the code it should be `private static double berekenBTW(double prijs)` (note the added `double`)

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know how I couldn't have seen this. Tried a lot but now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add a return type like this

```
private static double berekenBTW(double prijs)
{
    double btw = prijs * 0.21;
    return btw;
}
```